# VoIP on a remote VPN site

Tags: vpn, voip

I have a remote site that needs both data and voice.  We have a VPN L2L tunnel up and running back to the hospital, no problem. The concern is that I have data and voice on the same VLAN, and it is working, but we have not placed a large load on the remote office as of yet.  Is there a preferred setup to have data and VoIP connecting back through a VPN connection?  Our hardware at the remote site is a Cisco 5505.

Comment: You really don't want data and VoIP on the same VLAN. You will also really want to set up QoS with a priority queue for VoIP.

Comment: Are we talking about a VPN over the internet here or some sort of private link?

Comment: You could ad QoS on the device before the firewall, assuming you have a switch aggregating users / devices? Configure priority queuing on that device connecting to the FW (LAN interface).

Comment: Thanks for the follow ups, i have each port configured as interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 155
 switchport voice vlan 155
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

They can be on the same VLAN.  That will have no impact whatsoever.  Your main potential issue is the lack of QoS on the Internet path.  Interestingly, this is a special scenario where disabling split tunneling may be advisable.  What I mean is that if all Internet traffic is routed through the main site / hospital, you have some control over the inbound traffic to the branch (and from).

So, you want to configure a class based queueing mechanism whereby voice always gets priority and other traffic is shaped so as to prohibit the branch from getting overloaded on ingress.

Lastly, choose an Internet optimized codec for the telephony endpoints, iLBC i believe may be a good choice.

Comment: interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 155
 switchport voice vlan 155
 mls qos trust dscp
 spanning-tree portfast